# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor when installing pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, oserror

Recently I tried to run a program with python but when using one of the libraries I had installed (Eel) it gave me a bunch of errors. Same when I tried to uninstall the library or fix it, or list its location using pip. I figured I'd just reinstall python to get it fixed, but now I can't even install pip without getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23682, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8nq4wz5i\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, fixed by just waiting a day - even restarting my computer didn't work. But the next day as I went to test the issue, it worked again.